# Gradle syn fail: Could not find org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to solve this Gradle syn fail: `Could not find org.jetbrains.trove4j:trove4j:20160824` and below is the Gradle code for your reference also check many solutions but that didn't work out for me.

build.gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.parse.starter"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add compile 'org.jetbrains.trove4j: trove4j: 20160824' .